# What BTRFS mount options to use for long running streaming writes (like cameras)

Tags: mount, btrfs, camera

## Background

I have a NAS setup that's streaming camera data directly to disk on a file-an-hour rotation, then a job setup at the start of the day to concatenate the 24 files into a day file that is then stored in the same sub-volume (using ffmpeg)

I have the "live-cams" sub-volume with compression *disabled* and `nodatacow`.

## Intent

The thought was to limit the btrfs overhead as much as possible on the already compressed video files (no compression) and to try and limit the writing impact (nodatacow) of the files, as per [docs](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administration.html#datacow) :

> Updates in-place improve performance for workloads that do frequent overwrites, at the cost of potential partial writes, in case the write is interrupted (system crash, device failure).

*(Not super worried about partial writes as `ffmpeg` seems to be very capable of concatenating even partially corrupted video files that are still viewable.)*

### The crux

However looking at the description again **I'm not so sure this will help with anything**: I am unsure if "overwrites" effect the long streaming of the video file.
Is the writing of the file an act of constant overwriting?
Would it still help in this case?

## Question

Any guidance on potential mount options for the sub-volume is appreciated, and if you know what stats/system metrics I could look at to determine the A/B comparison, that would be great too!

## Additionally

[`autodefrag`](https://btrfs.readthedocs.io/en/latest/Administration.html#autodefrag) also caught my eye:

> Enable automatic file defragmentation. When enabled, small random writes into files (in a range of tens of kilobytes, currently it’s 64KiB) are detected and queued up for the defragmentation process. May not be well suited for large database workloads.

Again, **I am unsure** if the "writes into files" applies to the long running streaming of video, or it only effects existing "created" files.